# How do I set a radio button value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following Radio Buttons:

```
         <form id="bg" action="#">
            <span id="questionText">Question Test Here:</span><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="bga"><span id="A1"></span></input><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="bga"><span id="A2"></span></input><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="bga"><span id="A3"></span></input><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="bga"><span id="A4"></span></input><br/>
            <input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="OK!"/>
         </form>
```

I want to be able to set the values of each individual radio button with a different value using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give each radio element an id then $("#id").attr("value", "thevalueyouwant") for each one.

Answer (score 2):

```
var i=0;
$(':radio', $('#bg')[0]).each(function() {
  $(this).attr('value', i++).text("Option " + i);  // value=0, text="Option 1", etc.
});
```

Comment: Can you expand your example to set the text of the radio button and the value for each button?

Comment: done! You will notice that, in this example, the value is from 0-n, while the text is "Option 1" to "Option n+1" because the i is incremented when setting the value attribute. Of course, this is only an example, you can set whatever value you want, and whatever text you wish...